# How to replace string after specific character using python

Tags: python, file

How to replace string after specific character using python

I have a file with below contents

```
The Test file contents are as below "Test1"{
Serial  = 12345
IP      = 12.10.23.10
User    = user1
}
```

how do i replace the contents after the = symbol using python ?

for example i want to replace with below contents.

```
The Test file contents are as below "Test1"{
Serial  = 22330011
IP      = 1.1.1.1
User    = User_11
}
```

The contents after = symbols are not pre defined, hence substituting 12345 with 22330011 is not required here.
need a logic to find what is there after = symbol and replace it with the user defined value.

Comment: you can read all lines from the file and split the line w.r.t '=' and replace the last and append it

Comment: what is the logic of the substitutions?

Comment: lhs,rhs=line.split('=') you can change rhs and make newline=' = '.join([lhs,rhs])

Comment: @Kirushikesh, may you please provide an example to "replace the last and append it"

Comment: @Kirushikesh  I am seeing the below error:     data_left, data_right = data.split('=')
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Answer (score 0):

Lets say i have above data in temp.txt

```
file=open('temp.txt','r')
data=file.readlines()
outdata=[]
for line in data:
    try:
        lhs,rhs=line.split('=')
        rhs=input()
        outdata.append('='.join([lhs,' '+rhs,'\n']))
    except:
        outdata.append(line)

file.close()

file=open('temp.txt','w')
for line in outdata:
    file.write(line)
```

This code read from the file and ask the input from user for rhs and updates in the file again

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./T1.py", line 37, in <module>
    lhs,rhs=line.split("=")
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: My temp.txt contains just these lines                                                                                                                            Serial  = 12345
IP      = 12.10.23.10
User    = user1

Comment: can you please share your contents in test file

Comment: My test file contents are as below.                                                                                            The Test file contents are as below "Test1"{
Serial  = 12345
IP      = 12.10.23.10
User    = user1
}

Comment: @umer please try to use the edited code now